# Android Clarifai API com.clarifai.api.exception.ClarifaiThrottledException: TOO MANY REQUESTS

Tags: java, android, networking, clarifai

I am new to Android and having networking issues with an application that I'm making. When I make a request to Android (`return client.recognize(new RecognitionRequest(jpeg)).get(0);`) in the `doInBackground` of AsyncTask. However, I am getting the error:

> com.clarifai.api.exception.ClarifaiThrottledException: TOO MANY REQUESTS.

I assume it is because I am calling `client.recognize(new RecognitionRequest(jpeg)).get(0);` in the `doInBackground` but when I move it out of the AsyncTask it gives me "Too much work on MainThread".

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Uri selectedImageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            String[] tags = new String[10];
            RecognitionResult result = null;
            try {
                result = new ClarifaiTask().execute(photo).get();
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            ;
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getStatusCode() == RecognitionResult.StatusCode.OK) {
                    // Display the list of tags in the UI.
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                    int count = 0;

                    for (Tag tag : result.getTags()) {
                        if (count >= 10){
                            break;
                        }
                        tags[count++] = tag.getName();
                        System.out.println("TAG " + tag.getName());
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

private class ClarifaiTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, RecognitionResult> {
        @Override
        protected RecognitionResult doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            try {
                // Scale down the image. This step is optional. However, sending large images over the
                // network is slow and  does not significantly improve recognition performance.
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[0], 320,
                        320 * bitmaps[0].getHeight() / bitmaps[0].getWidth(), true);

            // Compress the image as a JPEG.
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            scaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            byte[] jpeg = out.toByteArray();

            // Send the JPEG to Clarifai and return the result.
            return client.recognize(new RecognitionRequest(jpeg)).get(0);
        } catch (ClarifaiException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Clarifai error", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"TOO MANY REQUESTS" indicates you are throttled. The possible reason is you are sending the requests too fast. The immediate solution would be creating a new app, then call the api with a slower pace.